# How to fix a table's column width on R Shiny using Formattable?

Tags: r, shiny, formattable

I would like to display the data frame on R Shiny using formattable. However, the solution here doesn't work.   https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/formattable/vignettes/formattable-data-frame.html

```
scores <- data.frame(id = 1:5,
                    prev_score = c(10, 8, 6, 8, 8),
                     cur_score = c(8, 9, 7, 8, 9),
                     change = c(-2, 1, 1, 0, 1))

width_formatter <- formatter("span",
                               style = x ~ style("width" = '100px'))


formattable(scores, list(width_formatter))
```

How can I do it? Thanks

Comment: You can do the same with `DT` would that work?

Answer (score 0):

Other than the DT solution, as said in the vignette of formattable, you can use elements from `formattable` with `knitr::kable`. Then you can use kableExtra to deal with the column width issue.

See http://haozhu233.github.io/kableExtra/use_kableExtra_with_formattable.html

how to use it in Shiny:
http://haozhu233.github.io/kableExtra/use_kable_in_shiny.html

General vignette:
http://haozhu233.github.io/kableExtra/awesome_table_in_html.html

Comment: It is a very nice package, thanks. However, the column_spec(3, width = "30em") function doesn't seem to work in the R Shiny environment. I tried changing the background color of the columns, and it works. Don't know why the width function doesn't.

Comment: @v_loves_avocados have you try to set `full_width = F` in `kable_styling`? If it doesn't work, can you share a reproducible example?